# hook into console windows

Tags: c++, windows, console

Thanks for fielding a question for me.  Right now I'm using C++ to set API hooks to intercept specific API functions.  I need to be able to hook into console windows.  I'm able to hook into win32 GUI windows but not console windows because of how the messaging queue is handled differently.

Can you point me in the direction that I would need to be able to achieve hooking into console windows?  Would I need a filter driver, kernel driver, etc...   So far I'm implementing trampoline hooking to achieve the functionality that I need for other reasons but they are not working on console applications.  I've also tried IAT hooking but to no avail.

Thanks for any help, tips or insight you can provide!

Comment: The reason that console windows are different is not due to *"the message queue being handled differently"*. The console is a different subsystem altogether.

Comment: I'm using SetWindowsHookEx to implement a global/system wide hook. I'm using a C# program that loads a dll (which implements the hook via a function that uses SetWindowsHookEx to set the hook and attaches to all running process via DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) to implement the global hook.  I'm using the MinHook library to hook API calls.  



I'm specifically looking to hook SetWindowsHookEx that I know is fired in the console app that I want to hook.  I'm trying to find out what is being passed from the console app in the idHook parameter of SetWindowsHookE

Comment: I've done some testing with API Monitor from rohitab.com and he is able to display all of the parameters/arguments being requested from SetWindowsHookEx being called from the same console app I'm trying to hook.  I'm not sure which method he is using to get that information out of the console app.  It's been killing me trying to find out how he is doing it.

Comment: From what I gather, it's a messaging queue issue that I'm not sure I can resolve in "user mode".